# Calculating raster land use zone characteristics for multiple circular buffers derived from lat long coordinates in QGIS 3.12.3

Tags: attribute-table, buffer, land-classification

Calculating  raster land use zone characteristics for multiple circular buffers derived from  lat long coordinates  in QGIS 3.12.3

I am running QGIS 3.12.3.  I have 150 circular buffers at 1KM, 4KM, 7KM, 14KM and 18KM in diameter at each buffer lat./long coordinate location. I need to calculate % land use characteristics (developed land, deciduous tree cover, coniferous tree, barren land etc.).   for each of those buffer diameters  at each of those lat/long coordinate locations.  So far I have only been able to calculate the land use characteristics at each point individually for each of the circular buffers which is very tedious.  I am assuming there is a way to perform this task instantaneously.

For the individual point for instance I have used the following  steps:

1. Derive the individual lat long point in CRS 4326 in the state of CT US.
2. Re-project that point to CRS 2234 in order to be able to calculate in a conventional measurement feet of KM.
3. Buffer by vector >geoprocessing tools > buffer at  1 KM diameter for instance (0.5 KM radius)
4. Raster >Extraction>Clip raster by extent> Input layer NLCD 2016 and Clipping extent Use layer extent.
5. With this clipped extent I use raster layer zonal statistics in order to generate  Statistics of land cover for each of the zones for 1 KM diameter (in this case).

[image: clipped image with land use zonal characteristics]

6. When I try to do this same procedure with 150 points the results look like this:

[image: Canvas when all points are added with 1 KM buffer at each and raster clipped by extent.]

For some reason the program reads instead of the buffer at the individual point it reads I guess the entire extent between the points.

I am relatively new to QGIS.